# How to apply linear transformation?

Tags: python, data-transformation, quasi-monte-carlo

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231391/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d), Martin Roberts mentioned that:

> ... to convert to a range of [-1,1], simply apply the linear
> transformation x:=2x+1. The result is
>
> (-0.361655, -0.657913, -0.900599)
>
> (-0.72331, 0.684174, 0.198802)
>
> (0.915035, 0.0262616, -0.701797)
>
> (0.55338, -0.631651, 0.397604)
>
> (0.191725, 0.710436, -0.502995),...

I am not specialist in math, I just want to know how to apply this transformation, in which part of the provided code?

```
# Use Newton-Rhapson-Method
def gamma(d):
    x=1.0000
    for i in range(20):
        x = x-(pow(x,d+1)-x-1)/((d+1)*pow(x,d)-1)
    return x

d=3
n=5

g = gamma(d)
alpha = np.zeros(d)                 
for j in range(d):
    alpha[j] = pow(1/g,j+1) %1
z = np.zeros((n, d))    
for i in range(n):
    z = (0.5 + alpha*(i+1)) %1

print(z)
```

Comment: Why should that be needed anywhere in that code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Nick Cox I need to generate points using R-sequence to be used in an algorithm and it should be in range [-1,1]. R-sequence is proposed by Martin Roberts and as he mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231391/how-can-one-generate-an-open-ended-sequence-of-low-discrepancy-points-in-3d), the linear transformation x:=2x+1can be used to generate points in range [-1,1]. For more details, please check [this link] (http://extremelearning.com.au/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-quasirandom-sequences/)

Answer (score 1):

Neither in this code nor in the related thread in math SE, you don't have that transformation. Also, to convert $[0,1]$ range to $[-1,1]$ range you need to apply the transformation $2x-1$; not $2x+1$. If you execute the code `print(2*z-1)`, you'll see the exact same output above.